# Return an array of arrays of prime factors for each number

Tags: javascript, primes

I was creating a small program to take in an array, then try to return an array of arrays of prime factors for each of the numbers in the given array. I think I am pretty close to having it, right now it seems to repeat the prime factors (i.e. for the number 21 it returns "3, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7"). I would prefer it to just return each prime factor once (i.e. for 21 it would return "3, 7"). I am sure it could just be a small adjustment. Also, if anyone has any input on another method for trying to achieve this, or any suggestions on cleaning up the code. At the moment, seems I could be somewhat unorthodox with my method currently. Thank you!

```js
var testArray = [3, 4, 5, 6, 21, 45, 101, 567, 30, 10];
var finalArray = [
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    [],
    []
];

factors(testArray, finalArray);

function factors(arr, emptyArr){
    for (var x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
        for (y = 2; y < arr[x]; y++){
            if (arr[x] % y !== 0){
                continue; 
            }
            for (i = 2; i < y; i++){
                if (y % i !== 0){
                    emptyArr[x].push(y);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


console.log(finalArray[4]);
```

Comment: This feels more like a [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) question, and the answers reflect that. You should check out that site.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I am pretty new to stack overflow. Is the codereview a different section of the site that acts as a different purpose? Excuse my lack of knowledge for this, just don't know if there's specific places I should ask my questions. If you could please elaborate on the difference between codereview and the stackoverflow site, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: There are I think over one hundred different sites under the Stack Exchange umbrella. When you go to a site you'll see a question mark button with links to help section for that site. There you will a succinct description of what the site is about and what kinds of questions should be asked there.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach:

```js
function primeFactor(n) {
  let factors = [];
  let divisor = 2;
  
  while (n >= 2) {
    if (n % divisor == 0) {
      factors.push(divisor);
      n = n / divisor;
    } else {
      divisor++;
    }
  }
  return factors;
}

var testArray = [3, 4, 5, 6, 21, 45, 101, 567, 30, 10];
var finalArray = [
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  [],
  []
]

testArray.forEach((num, i) => {
  primeFactor(num).forEach((el) => {
    finalArray[i].push(el)
  })
  finalArray.push()
})

console.log(finalArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Trial division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division):

```js
const trialDivision = value => {
    const primeFactors = [];
    let f = 2;
    let n = value;
    while (n > 1) {
        if (n % f === 0) {
            if (!primeFactors.includes(f)) {
                primeFactors.push(f);
            }
            n = n / f;
        } else {
            f++;
        }
    }
    return primeFactors;
};

const testArray = [3, 4, 5, 6, 21, 45, 101, 567, 30, 10];
const finalArray = testArray.map(trialDivision);
console.log(finalArray);
```